# Excluding duplicated class Tests

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlintest

I am running tests via Intellij and i have a small problem.

My code looks like that and the test code is not neccessary to show i think.

**MenuBarController.kt**:

```
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
class ExampleClass  {
```

Now if i run the tests via Intellij with coverage i have the problem, that i can see two classes ... Instead of one...

[image]

This is happening because the logger creates a class itself which is than allo coverage checked and this i dont want.

Can i exclude it somehow. ? I am using gradle.

Reprudaction code:

```
import mu.KotlinLogging

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
class ExampleClass  {
    var switch = false
    fun switchMe() {
        switch = !switch
        logger.info { switch }
    }
}
```

```
import io.kotlintest.shouldBe
import io.kotlintest.shouldNotBe
import io.kotlintest.specs.AnnotationSpec

class ExampleClassTest : AnnotationSpec() {

    @Test
    internal fun testSwitch() {
        var exampleClass = ExampleClass()
        exampleClass.switch shouldBe false
        exampleClass.switchMe()
        exampleClass.switch shouldBe true
    }
}
```

[image: This line is sho]

I think the Error is in KotlinLogging:
[image]

Comment: `why is there two classes` Because a class is created which contains both `logger` and `class MenuBarController`.

Comment: Hmm yeahr this i understand can i exclude the logger classes from beeing Coverage checked?

Comment: I don't know the answer . However, your understanding seems to be incorrect: it's not `logger` who creates a class. Your file has 2 entities, and kotlin creates a class (static, I guess), which encloses both entities.

Comment: Why would you want it to be excluded?

Comment: because it has nothing to do with my code its using a library which i just asume is correct. And my coverage is going down with that ...

Comment: Can you please share the reproducible code sample? Thanks

Comment: I added an code example :)

Comment: If you're using Jacoco, you can setup a class to be excluded from test coverage execution

Comment: Can you show us what is being considered not-covered in IntelliJ?

Comment: nop i cant because its not shown ... :/

Comment: I know the possibilities of Jacoco but i cant use it through ***** company restrictions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with only excluding it from the IntelliJ code coverage report, you can edit the run configuration to exclude files you don't want to see in the report:

[image]